# Django - Set current date as initial/default in a DateField form with SelectDateWidget

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Planning (models.Model):

#other fields#

month = models.DateField(default=date.today)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Planning'
```

And I have this model form:

```
class PlanningForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
#other fields#

month = forms.DateField(
    label='Mês/Ano',
    required=True,
    widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(
        attrs={'type': 'date',
               'value': date.today},}),
    error_messages={'required': '', },
)
 
    class Meta:
        model = Planning
        fields = '__all__'
```

The view:

```
def new_planning(request):
form = PlanningForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    if 'another' in request.POST:
        messages.success(request, ('Lançamento salvo com sucesso!'))
        return redirect('app:new_planning')
    else:
        return redirect('app:list_planning')
return render(request, 'app/pages/planning/new_planning.html', context={
    'form': form,
})
```

I'm using **SelectDateWidget** to show only month/year (I hid the day selector using CSS), like this:

[image]

The form is working as intended, but the issue is that I can't set the field to show the current date. When the form is rendered, it always shows the first date of the year.

In the above code, I tried to show the date using the value attribute from HTML. This works perfectly when I use `widget=forms.DateInput` but I imagine that the widget is changing the input completely so it doesn't work.

I also tried to add an initial value the same way I did for the model using the line `initial=date.today`, but for what i can get, [this only works for unbound forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial) and since my view runs a `if form.is_valid():`, that is not the case.

And I did try to set a range for the months, along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119390/selectdatewidget-not-getting-the-correct-initial-value), but with no luck.

Is there a way to set the current date with this specific widget?

**Edit:**

I could be completely wrong, but I'm assuming that the date input is converted to an actual date AFTER save. In [this widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#selectdatewidget) you can set a list/tuple/dict with the values you want to show. So if it is converting the values to dates after save, it make sense that it doesn't recognize the current date. To test this I added a list and dict with the months and years choice:

```
class PlanningForm(forms.ModelForm):

MONTHS = {1: ('this'), 2: ('is'), 3: ('text'), }
YEARS = ['and_so_is_this']

month = forms.DateField(
    label='Mês/Ano',
    required=True,
    widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(
        months=MONTHS,
        years=YEARS,
        attrs={'type': 'date', }),
    error_messages={'required': '', },
)
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by overriding the `__init__` method:

```py
from datetime import datetime

class PlanningForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...
    month = forms.DateField(
        label="Mês/Ano",
        required=True,
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={"type": "date"}),
        error_messages={
            "required": "",
        },
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['month'].initial = datetime.now()  # or timezone aware equivalent
    
    # ...
```

I think there's also an issue with the indentation and parentheses of your `month` field declaration

EDIT: It seems that the initial value must be a `datetime` object.

EDIT 2: The view and template I've used to test this

View:

```py
class PlanningView(FormView):
    form_class = PlanningForm
    template_name = "planning/form.html"
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{ form }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you not have to check if it's an edit or not?- does initial not override the value if it's an edit? I normally do the Initial stuff in the view, so I've never seen it done this way

Comment: It should happen before the data (request body) is processed as `cleaned_data`, right? To be honest I've only done that when I needed to access the instance on the ModelForm in weird edge cases. Like `self.fields['expiration'].initial = self.instance.created + timedelta(days=30)`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Clepsyd. I think that is correct now. I tried to add the code you suggested, but still shows the first date of the year.

Comment: @Zedh It was driving me slightly crazy so I actually tested it. Turns out the value that's expected is a datetime, not a date. datetime.now() works. Yes, even for a date field. I suppose it has to do with Javascript only having timestamps, no dates vs datetimes like Python.  I'll update the answer

Comment: @Clepsyd, thanks again, but I tried the proposed solution with datetime.now() and timezone.now() but is still shows the first date. You said that you tested and it works, so I don't know what I'm missing. In this widget you can set a list/tuple/dict with the values you want to show. So if it is converting the values to dates AFTER save, it make sense that it don't recognize the current date, i think? I actually tested this. I will post a screen of what i mean.

Comment: @Zedh Yes I have tried and it works. But note that I have also altered the `month` field on the form (cut any value setting from the widget). I also don't know how your view is set up so I've added it to my answer as well.

Comment: @Clepsyd, i updated my post with my view and the test i mentioned. I'm using FBV, but it is not doing anything special. In the test I removed the value from the widget.